# Foreach of a piped number array isnt breaking properly

Tags: powershell, foreach, break, pipeline

I dont quite understand this, but why doesn't the following code not work:

```
"start"
1..5 | foreach {
    "$_"
    break
}
"stop"
```

I've done a couple tests and this code does work properly :

```
"start"
foreach ($num in 1..5){
    "$num"
    break
}
"stop"
```

Is there a way to make the first example run properly? The last outputted line should be "stop".

Like so:

```
start
1
stop
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should know that you are using two entirely different language features when you use `foreach ($thing in $things) {}` vs. `$things | foreach { }`.

The first is the built-in `foreach` statement, and the second is an alias for `ForEach-Object`, and they work very differently.

`ForEach-Object` runs the scriptblock for each of the items, and it works within a pipeline.

The `break` statement in that case is only `break`ing out of the current item's execution. The "parent" so-to-speak doesn't know that the scriptblock exited because of `break` and it continues, executing the scriptblock for the next object.

---

How you would go about limiting the results depends on what you want to do.

If you just want to stop producing results, just don't return anything if the condition is met. You'll still run every iteration, but the results will be correct.

If you only need to return a certain number of items, like the first `N` items, the best way (from PowerShell v3 on) is to add `Select-Object`:

```
1..10 | ForEach-Object {
    $_*2
} | Select-Object -First 5
```

This will only execute 5 times, and it will return the sequence `2,4,6,8,10`.

This is because of how the pipeline works where each object gets sent through each cmdlet, and `Select-Object` can stop the pipeline so it doesn't keep executing.

Pre-version 3.0, the pipeline cannot be stopped in that way, and although the results will be correct, you won't have prevented the extra executions.

If you give more details on what your conditions are for exiting, I could give more input as to how you'd want to approach that particular problem (which may involve not using `ForEach-Object`).

Comment: you mention PSv3. how does select-object behave differently pre v3?